# bash find directories

Tags: linux, bash, directory

I am new to bash scripts. I'm just trying to make a script that will search through a directory and echo the names of all subdirectories.

The basis for the code is the following script (call it isitadirectory.sh):

```
     #!/bin/bash

     if test -d $1
         then
                echo "$1"
     fi
```

so in the command line if I type

```
       $bash isitadirectory.sh somefilename
```

It will echo somefilename, if it is a directory.

But I want to search through all files in the parent directory.

So, I'm trying to find a way to do something like

```
           ls -l|isitadirectory.sh
```

But of course the above command doesn't work. Can anyone explain a good script for doing this?

Comment: First you can execute a script if permission forexecution are not granted `chmod +x isitadirectory.sh`. Then you execute you script whit `./isitadirectory.sh`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following lines may give you an idea...what you are asking for

```
#!/bin/bash

for FILE in `ls -l`
do
    if test -d $FILE
    then
      echo "$FILE is a subdirectory..."
    fi
done
```

You may have a look into bash 'for' loop.

Comment: `ls -l` will not work. Also consider using * instead of parsing ls output ([Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)).

Answer (score 79):

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d
```

Answer (score 47):

In the particular case you are looking for a 1) directory which you know the 2) name, why not trying with this:

```
find . -name "octave" -type d
```

Answer (score 8):

try to use

`find $path -type d` ?

for current directory

`find . -type d`

Answer (score 6):

```
find ./path/to/directory -iname "test" -type d
```

I found this very useful for finding directory names using -iname for case insensitive searching. Where "test" is the search term.

Answer (score 4):

Here is already much solutions, so only for fun:

```
 file ./**/* | grep directory | sed 's/:.*//'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use:

```
ls -lR | isitadirectory.sh
```

(parameter -R is recursion)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure.. but maybe the tree command is something you should look at. http://linux.die.net/man/1/tree

```
tree -L 2 -fi
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed the full path so I ended up using

```
find $(pwd) -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -path '*/\.*' | sort
```

I have a lot of repos that I need to pull with one bash script. Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /path/where/to/look/for/dirs

# Iterate over files ending with .pub
echo -e "Pulling all repos"
FILES=`find $(pwd) -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -path '*/\.*' | sort`
for f in $FILES
do
    echo -e "pulling from repo $f..."
    cd $f
    git pull
done
```